# How to clear a Perl hash

Tags: perl

Let's say we define an anonymous hash like this:

```
my $hash = {};
```

And then use the hash afterwards. Then it's time to empty or clear the hash for
reuse. After some Google searching, I found:

```
%{$hash} = ()
```

and:

```
undef %{$hash}
```

Both will serve my needs. What's the difference between the two? Are they both identical ways to empty a hash?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, they are absolutely identical. Both remove any existing keys and values from the table and sets the hash to the empty list.

See [perldoc -f undef](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/undef.html):

> undef EXPR
>   undef   Undefines the value of EXPR, which must be an lvalue.  Use only
>                  on a scalar value, an array (using "@"), a hash (using "%"), a
>                  subroutine (using "&"), or a typeglob (using "*")...
>                  Examples:

```
               undef $foo;  
               undef $bar{'blurfl'};      # Compare to: delete $bar{'blurfl'};  
               undef @ary;  
               undef %hash;
```

*However*, you should not use `undef` to remove the value of anything except a scalar. For other variable types, set it to the "empty" version of that type -- e.g. for arrays or hashes, `@foo = (); %bar = ();`

Comment: They are almost identical. after undef, defined will return false, after =(), defined is still true.

Comment: I think rurban's objection to this answer is rather important. Maybe Ether could update his answer to mention that difference?

Comment: The use of defined(%hash) is deprecated, and shouldn't be used. So rurban's objection may eventually be moot. From the perl docs for "defined":

"Use of defined on aggregates (hashes and arrays) is deprecated. It used to report whether memory for that aggregate had ever been allocated. This behavior may disappear in future versions of Perl."

Answer (score 35):

`%$hash_ref = ();` makes more sense than undef-ing the hash. Undef-ing the hash says that you're done with the hash. Assigning an empty list says you just want an empty hash.